# When click table row alert that value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want, when I click table row below function process.. I got output but when I double click then only show the result.. But I need single click result

Here my javascript:

```js
 function found(row) {
     
     if (document.getElementById('ridee').checked) 
     {
      var table=document.getElementById("table");
       var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
       for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
       {
    rows[i].onclick = (function()
    { // closure
            
             return function() {
             $('#loading').show(); 
             var result = this.cells[1].textContent;
             var plate  = this.cells[6].textContent;
             var km  =  this.cells[7].textContent;
             var dataString = 'plate=' + plate + '&km='+km + '&res='+result;
             $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'km.php',
                   async: true,
                   data: dataString,
                   cache: false,
                   global: false,
                   success: function(result) 
                   {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                     var answer = confirm(result);
                     if (answer == true) 
                     {
                      return test();
                     }
                 
                    
                  }
              });
              
                                 
             }    
          })(i);
      }
     }
     else {
      alert("You are rider... So, You can't select");
      }
   }
```

I thought that return function is problem.. But without return function is not working.. Please anyone help

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle.net

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When/where do you call the "found" function?  If it's onclick of a row, then yes this definitely won't work.

Comment: your function takes `row` as argument but its unused. you are using jquery but you are also using pure javascript. this is mess. imo you should rewrite it and do it properly

Answer (score 0):

This will be a lot easier if each functional component was split out.

```
function getTableRows() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  return table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
}

function buildDataStringFromRow(row) {
  var result = row.cells[1].textContent;
  var plate  = row.cells[6].textContent;
  var km  =  row.cells[7].textContent;
  return 'plate=' + plate + '&km='+km + '&res='+result;
}

function postData(dataString, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'km.php',
    async: true,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    global: false,
    success: callback
  });
}

function onRowClick() {
  $('#loading').show();
  var dataString = buildDataStringFromRow(this);
  postData(dataString, function(result) {
    $('#loading').hide();
    var answer = confirm(result);
    if (answer == true) {
      return test();
    }
  }            
}

function found(row) {
  var tableRows = getTableRows(); 
  if (document.getElementById('ridee').checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
      tableRows[i].onclick = onRowClick.bind(tableRows[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    alert("You are rider... So, You can't select");
  }
}
```

Now that each function is very simple and easy to remove, now you may reason about which part is not working.

Comment: I want to hide selected row.. if i click three times